# Is there any "schedule" available for when the different sites are going to get the new beta theme?

Tags: discussion, design, beta-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [New Stack Exchange Beta Theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme)

The good old Sketchy theme for beta sites is now going to be replaced with a new theme that is similar to the look on the StackExchange.com site.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2

Even though I love the look on the Sketchy theme as an early look of a beta site, I also see that it will most likely harm the recruitment of new users that come from "outside" the SE community, and are not familiar with how SE sites are created through the Area51 process. Specifically when a beta has been around for a while, and have proved to be high quality, but lacks the quantity to graduate.

I specifically look forward to see [Musical Practice and Performance](http://music.stackexchange.com) get rid of the Sketchy look.

So I ask here now, when is it time?
Generally speaking, is there a ***prioritised list*** for the order the different sites gets the new look?

Comment: [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) is the general consensus. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin)'s off cavorting at SXSW this week, so this won't happen for existing sites until he gets back. No good rolling it out if he's not around to <strike>take the blame for all the bugs</strike> answer site-specific questions and concerns.

Comment: OK, good to know. Do you know if there is some plan for the order of which sites are first, or is this kind of random?

Comment: I don't know what order is planned, or if there's a plan for an order, but it should really go quickly enough not to matter much.