# Can the contrast of the new Beta UI's favorite tags highlighting be increased?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Stack Exchange Beta Theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme)

[My favorite Beta site](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) just got the post-Sketchy treatment, and the first thing I noticed is that *I can't see any of my favorite tagged posts!!*

Admittedly, I'm on a laptop that doesn't have a great screen. I could fiddle with the contrast, but how it's set now works well for everything else. But to see any contrast between a favorite tagged post and a normal post, I need to tilt my laptop backwards about 20 degrees.

I like the new theme, and am sure a lot of work went into it, but this is a major oversight in my opinion. Beta sites are the ones that need all the help they can get in attracting and keeping users, and we can't always control what screen we're viewing the site from. Hopping on quickly to check for new posts we're interested in is what the favorite tags are for, and if we can't quickly distinguish them, what good is it?

Comment: You could post this as an answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme

Comment: @YannisRizos-Done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126545/161719