# Really minor display issue in meta questions list

Tags: support, design

So if you look really closely at the following questions, there are a couple of minor differences between the 1st & 4th compared to 2nd & 3rd.

[image]

The aliasing looks different but that is only because the 1st & 4th title appear to use #3d3d3d while the middle two use #666666 so it plays tricks with your eyes. But why the different colors? I thought I was just getting tired but I took the screen shot and analyzed the colors with Photoshop to prove that it isn't just me.

This is a really minor nit, and I don't expect anyone to spend any real time on this - it is more to document my observation (and see if anyone else shares my observations) than any request for action. I viewed the source and all four headlines are marked up with the same tags pointing to the same styles, so I have to assume this is browser-dependent (as I see the issue in Chrome 20.0.1132.47 and not in Firefox). I do not have any user-styles, scripts or any plugins other than AdBlock. This persists through a page refresh and even a reboot.

Anyone else see this? I should I delete the question, pretend it doesn't bother me even a little, and never mention it again? :-)

Comment: "Really minor" kind of sums it up for me. :)

Comment: @JP. well like I said it wasn't a request for action, just a documentation of my observations.

Comment: Kinda related: [The "followed" link color in comments is distinctly brighter than the "fresh" link color](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126962/1438) for the new beta theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is intended: the darker version is a question you haven't visited yet, whereas the lighter version is one that you have:

```
.question-hyperlink {
  color: #3D3D3D;
}

.question-hyperlink:visited {
  color: #666;
}
```

Using colors (generally a less saturated variation of the normal link color) to denote what you've visited is a common UI element of websites.

Comment: Yep, got it, my bad. I guess maybe the bug is "link:visited class on meta is far too subtle for old folks."