# Flag history shows different formatting for answers and questions

Tags: bug, design, flag-history

Here is an excerpt of the four most recent entries in my flag history on [Meta.SE](//meta.stackexchange.com):

[image]

It seems like questions have a larger font size than answers (for no apparent reason) and removed posts are shaded (why is that?).

Here's a similar view on [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com):

[image]

...and on [TeX.SE](//tex.stackexchange.com) where the alignment is off:

[image]

Since [all sites should have a standardised flavour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/168244), something is still amiss here. Can this be fixed to be consistent? As an example, match how questions and answers are listed during [a search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=anything) with a `Q:` or `A:` prefix (for a `Q`uestion or `A`nswer). The current visuals are not intuitive.

OS: Windows
Browser 1: Google Chrome, Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Browser 2: Firefox Quantum 62.0.2 (64-bit)

Answer (score 13):

While I won't argue against this page getting some love and attention, I'm pretty sure that all of these differences are intentional.

It's pretty standard in various places that we indicate questions with larger fonts and answers with smaller ones. It makes it easy to see instantly what kind of post we're looking at without looking for the text that reads "asked" or "answered". It's a feature in my book.

As an example, here's a screenshot from the [10k tools page here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=last30days) (requires 10k):

> [image: "Most Commented" and "Most Edited" sections of 10k tools page showing three items in each section, in which one each is marked with a red "A" indicating an answer, which is shown in a smaller font size than the other two in each (unmarked), which are questions.]

The two list items marked with "A"s are answers, while the other items are questions and I can see that clearly because of the differing font sizes. [Here's the equivalent page on TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tools). We have no other indication of whether the posts here are questions or answers, which is different than on the flagging history page, which does. These size differences are valuable.

So, too, it's really valuable to have an immediately recognizable indication of whether a post is deleted or not, particularly on a flag review page. If you flagged something as spam, it's obvious that it was deleted. Again, a feature, not a bug.

The alignment on TeX is probably a bug, though... I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: While the difference may be valuable, there's no intuitive reason why there is a difference. Something more intuitive would be far better, like a `Q:` and `A:` prefix for `Q`uestions and `A`nswers (see [this search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=anything)).

Comment: Whether it's intuitive or not, I suppose depends on the person. I figured it out pretty easily without anyone explaining it to me... but you didn't ask for it to be made more obvious in your question, you stated that it serves no purpose, which isn't true, and asked for it to be standardized to one size, which I state here would be a loss to usability and clarity. If you'd like to propose an alternate in the form of a feature request, feel free. :) Also, I've retagged this as a bug because it's a bug report, not a FR.

Comment: Is this actually how it's supposed to be? The [10k tools](https://english.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=last30days) I know (ELU) have everything in the same size 18 font. The same goes for flags on that site.

Comment: @Laurel I've just looked at the 10k page on ELU and there are definitely two font sizes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVwPr.png.

Comment: @Catija that’s not what I see. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOrYv.jpg (screenshot taken on mobile Safari but it’s the same on desktop Chrome)