# Ransom note look alike font size mixture in tools page

Tags: bug, design

The font size of the tools page (e.g. this page https://tex.stackexchange.com/tools) mixes different font sizes. The links to deleted questions seem to use another font size than the one to answers:

[image]

Comment: Yes…? The flag list uses the same style.

Comment: @Xufox I can't believe this layout is intended -- this just looks so horrible -- this simply must be a bug

Comment: Related: [Flag history shows different formatting for answers and questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315807/323179).

Comment: @Laurel Thanks for the link -- it seems indeed to be the same bug (I refuse to call something like that intended feature)

Comment: "Feechur" [is probably the word you want](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feechur).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ah, yes! "Feechur" nails it!