# Inconsistent font size for links to questions and answers on badge page

Tags: bug, design, badges

Some badges have links to specific questions and answers where you (or another user) earned them. Since most badges can only be earned on either questions *or* answers, it's not really obvious links to questions have font size 16 and links to answers font size 13. This is most easily seen for the [Announcer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer?userid=295232); the third entry below is a question, the others are answers.

[image]

I'm not really buying [the argument that this might be intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315807/295232); the [Top Network Posts widget](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/116151/glorfindel?tab=profile#change-post-sort) on a user's profile shows questions and answers in the same font size.

[image]

Comment: Well, it is “consistent” to other parts of the page, e.g. the 10k tools or the flag history: [Ransom note look alike font size mixture in tools page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322028/289905).